# SQL Server : truncation error with plenty of room in char destination data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am attempting to do an `insert` from a `select` statement in SQL Server 2008 R2. The destination column's data type is `char(7)` and I have verified the `len()` and `datalength()` of the source column to be no longer than 6.

I am getting truncation error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 219
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

I have verified using temp tables that an insert into a `char(9)` column works, but unfortunately the destination database will not support the data type change.

UPDATE: I was able to do the insert as required by adding a DISTINCT clause to the select statement in question, however the number of rows remains the same. So, I guess the reformatted question is why does adding the distinct clause return no error message even if the data is the same? Thanks!

Comment: if the field will be taking variable length strings try varchar(7)

Answer (score 0):

What character set are you using? Some character sets have characters that take up two bytes. However the length function will still count them as 1.

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, and I believe datalength() does return the byte details as well, thanks! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bill and David. But if most of the characters from your source are multi-byte then (some characters even take up 3 bytes) then you may need to use something like varchar(50) just to make sure your field is big enough to avoid truncation errors.

Comment: I agree as well, however; "...the destination database will not support the data type change."

Comment: If you supply the DDL & SQL I'll be happy to try to reproduce the case on my server.

Comment: Are the source & target character sets the same? Are you using a data migration or ETL tool? Is there a trigger on the target table? If you export the source & target result sets are they identical?